# Update a value in a table from another table in Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

After I've imported data into a temp table from an xls file, I want to update a hex field with a hex value from another table.  The import works and if I run the following sql in PHPMyAdmin the field is updated. I've tried several ways to get sql to work in PHP Zend 1.11 with no luck. Here is the sql I want to execute in Zend 1.11 and php.

```
UPDATE table1_temp INNER JOIN table2
ON table_temp.CODE = table2.CODE 
SET table1temp.person_ID = table2.ID
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
    $sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
    $update = $sql->update();
    $update-> table (table1_temp)
           ->INNER JOIN table2 ON table1_temp.CODE = table2.CODE 
           ->SET (t_table1_temp.PERSON_ID = table2.ID'):
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($update);
    $statement->execute();
```

All suggestions welcome.